# stopping a python program with python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program that I run with thread, like this:

```
thread.start_new(call_chat_serv, (usr_name, ))
```

and this is call chat serv:

```
def call_chat_serv(_name):
    global getting_from_user
    os.system("python.exe Chat.py "+ str(_name))
    while (not getting_from_user):
        pass
```

now, when I set getting from user to true, the program "Chat.py" still runs.
How can I terminate this program? and by terminate I mean close Chat.py

Comment: use python subprocess instead?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am not that good with threads. Please help :(

Comment: You can create with subprocess and kill with os: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612#4791612

Comment: Why are you using `thread` instead of `threading`?

Comment: I actually don't know the difference, is there a way to kill a thread with threading?

Comment: Why are you running `Chat.py` in a new Python process with `system`? Do you know how to write a module?